# What are the typical use cases that require taking ownership of the self argument?

Tags: rust

In the Rust book [Method Syntax chapter](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/method-syntax.html), there's an example of taking ownership of `self`:

```
struct Circle {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    radius: f64,
}

impl Circle {
    fn reference(&self) {
        println!("taking self by reference!");
    }

    fn mutable_reference(&mut self) {
        println!("taking self by mutable reference!");
    }

    fn takes_ownership(self) {
        println!("taking ownership of self!");
    }
}
```

What are the typical use cases that require taking ownership of `self`? Is it only when `self` is a value on the stack (where it will be copied)?

Comment: *a value on the stack* — everything is on the stack in some way or the other. Sometimes, the item on the stack points to something on the heap though.

Comment: Copy vs move - that depends on the `Copy` trait, not on stack vs heap, right?

Comment: I use the phrase "a value on the stack" because it is in the book chapter's exlaination. What I think the author means is when self is a primitive type which implements the Copy trait. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking ownership makes sense when the object is invalidated by the method. Imagine a method `Iterator.drop(u32)`, implemented as returning a new object instead of modifying the existing one. Calling additional methods on the original iterator would lead to inconsistencies.

Other examples for such invalidation would be different sorts of wrappers.